# Joining several tables in SSMS without double counting records

Tags: sql-server

I have several new tables in my data warehouse that I need to find a way to connect correctly. My ultimate goal is to see a customer's full information based on their first Program registration.

Apologies in advance because the background for this post is lengthy.

I am working in SSMS for this. There are 7 tables that are relevant here, and three Program types (Activity, League, Day Camp). Below is dummy data.

**Individual**

```
personID  firstname  lastname
1         mark       smith
2         mike       boy
```

**Activity**

```
activityID   activityName   createdDate  activityType
100          skating        01-01-2019   january
200          hockey         01-10-2019   february
```

**ActivityRegistration**

```
activityID  activityName  personID  createdDate  paidAmount
100         skating       1         01-06-2019   10
200         hockey        1         01-12-2019   25
100         skating       2         01-13-2019   10
```

**League**

```
leagueID  leagueName    createdDate   leagueType
1         Adult Hockey  01-10-19      West
```

**LeagueRegistration**

```
leagueID  leagueName   personID  createdDate  paidAmount
1         Adult Hockey 1         01-16-19     100
1         Adult Hockey 2         01-12-19     100
```

There are also **Day Camp** and **Day Camp Registration** tables that have the same data setup as the above four.

```
select I.personid, 
       I.firstname, 
       I.lastname,
       'Activity' as Source,
       (isnull(ActivityPay,0) + isnull(LeaguePay,0) + isnull(DCPay,0)) as 'TotalPaid',
       (isnull(TotalActivities,0) + isnull(TotalLeagues,0) + isnull(TotalDCs,0)) as 'TotalRegistrations'
from Individuals I

       left join (
            select PersonID, sum(paidamount) as 'ActivityPay', count(registrationid) as 'TotalActivities'
            from ActivityRegistration
            group by PersonID
                 ) A on I.PersonID = A.PersonID

       left join (
            select personid, sum(PaidAmount) as 'LeaguePay', count(registrationid) as 'TotalLeagues'
            from ro.vw_MaxGalaxy_LeaguePlayerRegistrations
            group by PersonID, ArenaName
                 ) L on I.PersonID = L.PersonID

where I.PersonID in
   (
   select PersonID
   from ActivityRegistration
   where CreatedDate in (
      select
         (
         select min(Event)
         from (values (firstleague), (firstactivity), (firstdaycamp)) as v (Event)
         ) as FirstRegistration
         from
             (
             select i.personid, i.FirstName, i.LastName, min(l.createddate) as 'firstleague', min(a.createddate) as 'firstactivity', min(d.createddate) as 'firstdaycamp'
             from Individuals I
             left join ActivityRegistration A on I.PersonID = A.PersonID
             left join LeaguePlayerRegistration L on I.PersonID = L.PersonID
             left join DayCampRegistration D on I.PersonID = D.PersonID
             group by i.PersonID, i.firstname, i.lastname 
             ) as derived
         )
    )
```

This is basically what I have come up with. This makes a faulty assumption that createdDate can be used as a unique identifier, and it only looks at one Program Type at a time (notice how it pulls from `ActivityRegistration` only; I `UNION` with the other two program types in my SSMS environment). This works to get me a person and their total programs/total spend, but does not allow me to look at the first program.

I have attempted to pull this in other ways, but I continuously get hung up on pulling the min(createdDate) as well as pulling ActivityID. If I group by ActivityID and PersonID, I would get min(createdDate) for each ActivityID.

The ultimate goal is to have a table that relates all of that information back to the customer level (and including a simple `'Activity' as Source` line).

**Goal Table**

```
personID firstName lastName firstProgramSource firstProgramID firstProgramName firstProgramType totalPrograms  totalSpend
1        mark      smith    Activity           100            skating          january          3              135 
2        mike      boy      League             1              Adult Hockey     West             3              110
```

If I haven't rambled too much, is there any way to achieve what I am attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. It looks like you were getting stuck in the WHERE clause.  An easier strategy would be to gather two different kinds of aggregates: Get SUM/Count separate from Min/Max.  Your query would look more like this:

```
select I.personid, 
        I.firstname, 
        I.lastname,
        --'Activity' as Source,
        CASE WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') < IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN 'Activity' 
            WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') > IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN 'League'
            ELSE 'Neither'
        END AS FirstProgramSource,
        CASE WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') < IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN A1.ActivityName 
            WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') > IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN L1.LeagueName
            ELSE 'Neither'
        END AS FirstProgramName,
        CASE WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') < IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN A1.ActivityType 
            WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') > IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN L1.LeagueType
            ELSE 'Neither'
        END AS FirstProgramType,       
        (isnull(ActivityPay,0) + isnull(LeaguePay,0) + isnull(DCPay,0)) as TotalPaid,
        (isnull(TotalActivities,0) + isnull(TotalLeagues,0) + isnull(TotalDCs,0)) as TotalRegistrations
from Individuals I

        left join (
            select PersonID, sum(paidamount) as ActivityPay, count(registrationid) as TotalActivities
            from ActivityRegistration
            group by PersonID
                    ) A on I.PersonID = A.PersonID

        left join (
            select PersonID, sum(PaidAmount) as LeaguePay, count(registrationid) as TotalLeagues
            from LeagueRegistrations
            group by PersonID--, ArenaName
                    ) L on I.PersonID = L.PersonID

--   Get the "First Activity" separately from your other aggregate (sum, count, etc).
        left join ( --TOP 1 will eliminate duplicates, if you have two with the same FirstDate
            select TOP 1 PersonID, A.ActivityID, ActivityName, ProgramType, FirstDate 
            from (   -- SELECT PersonID, ActivityID, Min(CreatedDate) FirstDate 
                    SELECT PersonID, Min(CreatedDate) FirstDate 
                FROM ActivityRegistration 
                GROUP BY PersonID --, ActivityID
                ) AFirst
                INNER JOIN ActivityRegistration AR ON AFirst.PersonID = AR.PersonID 
                    AND AFirst.FirstDate = AR.CreatedDate
                INNER JOIN Activity A ON AR.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
            ) A1 on I.PersonID = A1.PersonID

        left join (
            select PersonID, L.LeagueID, LeagueName, LeagueType, FirstDate 
            from (SELECT PersonID, LeagueID, Min(CreatedDate) FirstDate 
                    FROM LeagueRegistration 
                    GROUP BY PersonID, LeagueID
                    ) LR 
                    INNER JOIN League L ON LR.LeagueID = L.LeagueID
            ) L1 on I.PersonID = L1.PersonID
```

Since I don't have your DB, I can't be 100% certain that this will run on the first try, but I'm pretty close and you can see the concept.

One last thing: If you have any `ActivityRecord` rows where one person has duplicate "FirstDate" rows, then you will have to add another GROUP BY clause:

```
select I.personid, 
        I.firstname, 
        I.lastname,
        --'Activity' as Source,
        CASE WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') < IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN 'Activity' 
            WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') > IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN 'League'
            ELSE 'Neither'
        END AS FirstProgramSource,
        CASE WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') < IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN A1.ActivityName 
            WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') > IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN L1.LeagueName
            ELSE 'Neither'
        END AS FirstProgramName,
        CASE WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') < IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN A1.ActivityType 
            WHEN IsNull(A1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') > IsNull(L1.FirstDate,'1/1/1900') THEN L1.LeagueType
            ELSE 'Neither'
        END AS FirstProgramType,       
        (isnull(ActivityPay,0) + isnull(LeaguePay,0) + isnull(DCPay,0)) as TotalPaid,
        (isnull(TotalActivities,0) + isnull(TotalLeagues,0) + isnull(TotalDCs,0)) as TotalRegistrations
from Individuals I

        left join (
            select PersonID, sum(paidamount) as ActivityPay, count(registrationid) as TotalActivities
            from ActivityRegistration
            group by PersonID
            ) A on I.PersonID = A.PersonID

        left join (
            select PersonID, sum(PaidAmount) as LeaguePay, count(registrationid) as TotalLeagues
            from LeagueRegistrations
            group by PersonID--, ArenaName
            ) L on I.PersonID = L.PersonID

--   Get the "First Activity" separately from your other aggregate (sum, count, etc).
        left join ( 
            select PersonID, A.ActivityID, A.ActivityName, A.ActivityType, FirstDate 
            from (  --one more GROUP BY to include the MIN ActivityID for any FirstDate. 
                SELECT PersonID, Min(A.ActivityID) ActivityID, FirstDate
                FROM (
                    -- get the first date
                        SELECT PersonID, Min(CreatedDate) FirstDate 
                    FROM ActivityRegistration 
                    GROUP BY PersonID 
                    ) AFD INNER JOIN ActivityRecord AR1 
                      ON AFD.PersonID=AR1.PersonID AND AFD.FirstDate=AR1.CreatedDate
                GROUP BY PersonID, FirstDate
                ) AFirst                    
                INNER JOIN Activity A ON AFirst.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
            ) A1 on I.PersonID = A1.PersonID

-- similar pattern for League
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense conceptually. What doesn't work from this solution and what has been tripping me up is in those last two joins where you need to group by PersonID and ActivityID. With that logic, there will be a record returned for every occurrence of a PersonID with an ActivityID. In my original data in the post, it returns two rows for Mark Smith for both of his activities, and then a third for his league. I'm aiming to only see one.

Comment: Okay. I see the problem. I will modify my answer by commenting out my mistake and replacing it with a better answer.

Comment: This new strategy is to only grab the date of the first (ever) activity for a person and then link the rest to it. I didn't show the matching logic for League. I could add that if the first query works.   Oh, one last thing: the reason for adding an extra join instead of a sub-query or WHERE clause, is because I've found these types of JOIN clauses to run quicker (for some reason). Also, I find it easier to troubleshoot by isolating (commenting-out other clauses) sometimes. Divide & conquer strategy.

Comment: This is so close to working. The only issue I am seeing now is that the TOP 1 command is not referring to the any PersonID grouping, thus it is only giving the TOP 1 of all records. This issue is leading the FirstProgramSource/Name/Type being Neither for every record. Is it possible with my data to actually pull this?

Comment: Ok. If you don't have any `ActivityRegistration` records where a person has two identical "first dates", then you can just remove the `TOP 1` syntax.

Comment: The 2nd query is probably exactly what you need. It seems bulky and excessive, but sometimes SQL queries are like the Towers of Hanoi problem and you have to stack & unstack multiple queries to get it "just so".

Comment: I got it! You were right in the second query being essentially what I needed. I had to update a little bit of logic from here, but you helped me get the solution. Thank you so much!